# Libgdx game is pixelated on lower resolution android device

Tags: android, libgdx

I created an android game using libgdx, on desktop it looks fine. But when I try it on an android device with a screen resolution of 720p the assets are pixelated and not as good when I run the game on desktop mode. The game looks fine though when using an android device with a 1080p resolution. So what should I do? should I create larger images for lower resolution devices? but I think that will slow down the game.

Comment: Read up on OpenGL texture filtering.